# How many domains per each TLD are registered?

Tags: domains

I hope this is the right place to ask: For a little research I need to know how many Domains per TLD are registered (approximately). I've only found some lists with the top 10 TLDs and their number of registered domains...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should give you a pretty good list, http://www.domaintools.com/internet-statistics/. This one lists only the top few TLDs.

The site http://www.dailychanges.com/ will give you counts by registrar and if you click on each registrar it will list the domains registered.  This information can be downloaded and with the proper scraper code you could probably batch download all of the domains by registrar and use that information to create a list of TLDs and the number currently registered.  This would take some serious work though.

Comment: it now has an extensive collection of gtld